# ConfirmationBox from codebehind, wait for answer

Tags: c#, asp.net

From my code behind, in my update method, I have to ask the user if he wants to overide some particular value. If so, overide, if not, continue with the saving without saving this value.

In my aspx I have this javascript function:

```
function ConfirmationBox(msg) {
    var ovd = document.getElementById("hdnOveride"); //gets a HiddenField
        if (confirm(msg) == true) {
            ovd.value = "1";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            ovd.value = "0";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

From codebehind, I call this function. And then I check the value of my HiddenField "hdnoveride". If its 1 I save, otherwise I don't.

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Test", "javascript:ConfirmationBox('overide?');", true);

if (hdnOveride.Value == "1"){
      //Save the value
}
```

The problem is that my code doesn't wait for the user to answer the confirm box before it continues. I have tried using Thread.Sleep() while hdnOveride is not set like this:

```
while (hdnOveride.Value == "notset") {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

But it just stops everything, so the popup box never shows when I do this.

How can I tell the system to wait for an answer before continuing with the code?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you checking to see if the old value has changed to a new value?

Comment: In ASP.NET there's no way to prompt the user for input like this in the middle of a block of code running on the server. You have to put the javascript for the prompt on the page as you are doing, then let the page complete and be sent to the client, and then check the value on the _next_ postback.

Comment: @TimBJames I checked and the value never changes. Since my hiddenField is never set to "1" before the end of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then, I used Panel instead to ask the question to my users as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7677000/454157